# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type for pcap_t structure

Tags: c, struct, libpcap

I am coding in C and using libpcap library.
I want to see the fields of a pcap_t structure, but always have the error :

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Minimal code is the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int main()
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
    handle=pcap_open_live("eth0", 65535, 1, 1, errbuf);

    printf("Handle%d\n", handle->fd);

    pcap_close(handle);
}
```

Compilation done by :

```
gcc test.c -lpcap
```

According to http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-9/libpcap/pcap-int.h, the pcap_t structure does have this field.
The libpcap is normally included, so I do not understand at all.

Thanks!

**Conclusion:** Olaf seems to be right : I have this error because I am not able to access the pcap_t structure.
As Antti Haapala said, pcap_t struct is not defined in pcap/pcap.h but in another file.

I did manage to do what I wanted to do anyway, even without access to the fields of the structure.

Problem solved, thanks for your help !

Comment: Read about opaque pointers in C. The `struct` definition is likely hidden as you are not supposed to access it.

Comment: Yep, it looks like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **-int** in [`pcap-int.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-9/libpcap/pcap-int.h) stands for [**internal**](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-9/libpcap/FILES). However you're not including this header in your code.

Notice that [`pcap.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-9/libpcap/pcap.h) itself does not include this header, neither does it contain a full declaration of `struct pcap`; instead just using the forward declaration in typedef:

```
typedef struct pcap pcap_t;
```

Just try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap-int.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int main()
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
    handle=pcap_open_live("eth0", 65535, 1, 1, errbuf);

    printf("Handle%d\n", handle->fd);

    pcap_close(handle);
}
```

---

Alas it seems that this internal header is not installed in Linux nor on Mac. For an extra-ugly hack you can try copying the `pcap-int.h` from the link.

Comment: Just got a 

    fatal error: pcap/pcap-int.h: No such file or directory

Did it work for you ?

Comment: hmm sorry my network was lagging, I thought I posted an update, but it had failed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do, instead, either

```
printf("Handle%d\n", pcap_fileno(handle));
```

if you're *not* going to use `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`/kqueues/etc. on the descriptor in question, or

```
if (pcap_get_selectable_fd(handle) != -1)
    printf("Handle%d\n", pcap_get_selectable_fd(handle));
```

if you *are* going to use `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`/kqueues/etc. on the descriptor in question.

The difference is that, at least currently, there will always be a file descriptor for a `pcap_t` on UN*Xes, but there is no guarantee that you will be able to use `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll()`/kqueues/etc. on that descriptor.  On newer versions of BSD-flavored OSes (including OS X), you *can* do so on descriptors for normal network interfaces, but you can't do so on some older versions of BSD-flavored OSes, and you have to work around an issue on other older versions of BSD-flavored OSes (see [the man page for `pcap_get_selectable_fd()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_get_selectable_fd.3pcap.html) for details), and you also can't do so on some specialized devices such as Endace DAG cards.

So, in some cases, `pcap_get_selectable_fd()` returns -1, which means "there *is* no FD on which you can do `select()`, etc., for this `pcap_t`".

(And, yes, it is intentional that `pcap-int.h` is not installed and that `pcap.h` doesn't declare the members of a `struct pcap_t`; the contents of that structure are subject to change from release to release, and newer libpcap releases have removed a *lot* of platform-dependent and device-dependent fields from that structure.)