# libpcap error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘pcap’

Tags: c++, pcap

I am writing a C++ multithread program using libpcap. I need to save as class member the `pcap_t*` handles (one per thread) returned by the `pcap_open_live` function, and I would like to do it by using a `std::vector` of smart pointers or at least using the `new` operator so that, later, I can call `pcap_breakloop` in the class destructor.

Whatever thing I tried, the compiler game me errors like `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘pcap’` or like `forward declaration of ‘pcap_t’ {aka ‘struct pcap’}`. However, it looks like `pcap_t` is just a typedef for `struct pcap`, and I could not find the actual definition of that struct. I read that this definition should be "opaque" to the programmer, but I really cannot find a way to make it work.

Thanks to whoever will help!

Comment: Since `pcap` has been forward declared, the compiler can't know its size. Do check if there's some function defined in the library that returns the size of the `struct`. If not, it would be nice if you could show how and where you are trying this in a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so perhaps we could suggest alternatives. You might also be a victim of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: You are not supposed to manipulate those pointers directly, and you should not try to get the size of the objects they point to. If you want to save those pointers in vector, you can do so, but you can only work with pointers, not with the objects they point to. You **can** wrap them in smart pointers, but you will have to use a custom deleter.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 there is no such function, the pointer is supposed to be opaque, and not directly used by the user of the library.

Comment: In that case, I strongly suspect an XY problem. OP, An MRE could really help in finding a proper solution to the real problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dereferencing pointer to incomplete type for pcap\_t structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452602/dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type-for-pcap-t-structure)

Comment: @cecchi If you have found a solution to your _question_, then post an _answer_! This is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

To quote [cppreference.com's page on `unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> `std::unique_ptr` may be constructed for an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/incomplete_type) T, such as to facilitate the use as a handle in the [pImpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). If the default deleter is used, T must be complete at the point in code where the deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment operator, and reset member function of `std::unique_ptr`. (Conversely, `[std::shared_ptr][4]` can't be constructed from a raw pointer to incomplete type, but can be destroyed where T is incomplete).

`pcap_t` is a type that, except internally to libpcap, is always and forevermore an incomplete type.  The contents of a `pcap_t` are subject to change between libpcap releases, *and* a `pcap_t *` points to a block of memory that contains a `pcap_t` followed by private data that's dependent on the OS on which you're running and the type of packet source to which it refers.

So the default deleter cannot be used.  That's what your code does, so it won't work.

You'll have to use a custom deleter, which would have to call `pcap_close()` on the raw `pcap_t *` to free what it points to - and to free what various pointers in both the `pcap_t` *and* the private data points to, as well as releasing any *other* resources, such a file descriptors.

This may require two levels of wrapping, one of which is `unique_ptr` and one of which wraps a `pcap_t *` to give it enough C++ness that it *has* a C++ destructor, i.e. create a class with a destructor that calls `pcap_close()` and a `unique_ptr<pcap_t *>` as a member.

It may be that one of the C++ wrappers for libpcap (which is *NOT* a C++ library - it's a C library) will help here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved

Simply wrapping the `pcap_t*` inside a class and then creating a vector with elements of that class made everything work without problems. Thank you everybody!